# Asp.net Menu Control - indivdual css classes on LI's

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-4.0, webforms

Anyone know of a good menu control that could be used in Web Forms (.net 4)?  Tried using the built in menu control, but the nav I've got needs individual classes on each LI, and that one only allows for one class on the UL.

Happy to build one manually if need be, but if there is a pre built one that is up to it, then that would be ideal.

Downloaded the APN soft menu, but that seems to have the same problems.

Comment: Heh - starting to look like I'll need to build my own after all :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And I did end up just building it up myself.  Used web.sitemap and a repeater with SiteMapDatasource, but set the classes based on the page url at the time.  Works well.